# react-router v4 with Typescript: how to use the `component` parameter as jsx element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-v4

I have this component which wraps the `Route` component of `react-router-dom`:

`// AuthRoute.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { RouteProps } from "react-router";

interface Props extends RouteProps {
  user: any
}

const AuthRoute: React.SFC<Props> = ({ user, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  console.log("auth route...", user);
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={matchedProps => (
      !user || user.expired
        ? <Redirect to="/login"/>
        : <Component {...matchedProps} /> <--- error here
    )}/>
  );
};
```

The error is `element type Component does not have any construct or call signatures`

How can I render the `Component`? either with or without parameter renaming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you want to render passed component with some extra props you should use [cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) for this purpose:

```
var elem = React.cloneElement(component, matchedProps);
```

So your code can look similar to this:

```
return (
    <Route {...rest} render={matchedProps => (
      !user || user.expired
        ? <Redirect to="/login"/>
        : React.cloneElement(component, matchedProps) 
    )}/>
  );
```